# Phalcon php orm can't relate tables

Tags: php, orm, model, entity-relationship, phalcon

I'm trying to setup a 3 tables relationship in phalcon, but it doesn't seem to work. Could anyone plese tell me what am I doing wrong? Here is a ERD of these tables: [(ERD diagram)](http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=k4h4ee&s=8#.U1D_6Pl_s1M) Here is my code from models and controller

```
Authors.php (Model)

<?php




class Authors extends \Phalcon\Mvc\Model
{

/**
*
 * @var integer
*/
public $ID;

/**
*
* @var string
*/
public $Name;

/**
*
* @var string
*/
public $LastName;

/**
* Initialize method for model.
*/
public function initialize()
{
  $this->setSource('Authors');
  $this->hasMany('ID', 'Authorbook', 'AuthorID');
}

/**
* Independent Column Mapping.
*/
public function columnMap()
{
  return array(
      'ID' => 'ID', 
      'Name' => 'Name', 
      'LastName' => 'LastName'
  );
}
```

Books.php(Model)

```
<?php




class Books extends \Phalcon\Mvc\Model
{

 /**
  *
  * @var integer
  */
 public $ID;

 /**
  *
  * @var string
  */
 public $Name;

 /**
  *
  * @var string
  */
 public $YearPublished;

 /**
 *
 * @var string
 */
 public $Picture;

/**
 * Initialize method for model.
 */
public function initialize()
{
    $this->setSource('Books');
    $this->hasMany('ID', 'Authorbook', 'BookID');
}

/**
 * Independent Column Mapping.
 */
 public function columnMap()
 {
     return array(
        'ID' => 'ID', 
        'Name' => 'Name', 
        'YearPublished' => 'YearPublished', 
        'Picture' => 'Picture'
    );
 }

 }

}
```

AuthorBook.php (Model):

```
<?php
 class Authorbook extends \Phalcon\Mvc\Model
 {

 /**
   *
  * @var integer
  */
 public $ID;

 /**
  *
  * @var integer
 */
public $AuthorID;

/**
 *
 * @var integer
 */
public $BookID;

/**
* Initialize method for model.
*/
public function initialize()
{
  $this->setSource('AuthorBook');
  $this->belongsTo('AuthorID', 'Authors', 'ID');
  $this->belongsTo('BookID', 'Books', 'ID');
}

 /**
 *   Independent Column Mapping.
 */
public function columnMap()
{
return array(
    'ID' => 'ID', 
    'AuthorID' => 'AuthorID', 
    'BookID' => 'BookID'
);
}

}
```

AdminController.php

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $this->view->disableLevel(View::LEVEL_MAIN_LAYOUT);
    $this->view->setVar('books', Books::find()->toArray());
}

}
```

So my question is how can I get access to the author of a book? Because when I print out my books array in view only thing I get is :

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
(
    [ID] => 1
    [Name] => Javascript: The Good Parts
    [YearPublished] => 2014-04-18
    [Picture] => javascript-the-good-parts.jpg
)
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the hasManyToMany for n-n relationship for the Authors and Books models, (if I'm not wrong, Author has many Books and Books has many Authors)

so you models should be like this:
for Authors:

```
public function initialize(){
  $this->setSource('Authors');
  $this->hasManyToMany('ID', 'Authorbook', 'AuthorID', 'BookID', 'Books', 'ID', array(
'alias' => 'books'
));
}
```

same for the Books model, we have to use the hasManyToMany function:

```
public function initialize(){
      $this->setSource('Books');
      $this->hasManyToMany('ID', 'Authorbook', 'BookID', 'AuthorID', 'Author', 'ID', array(
    'alias' => 'authors'
    ));
    }
```

the AuthorBook model relations are correct.

Now you can get the author(s) of a book with a simple call to the alias that we have defined in the relations:

```
$book = Books::findFirst();
$bookAuthor = $book->authors->toArray()
```

that's it.

Answer (score 0):

I copied an [example code on Phalcon site](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/models.html#defining-relationships) to test model relationship and ran into similar issue. I need to specific the namespace when set relationship. For example, in function initialize of Robots class

`public function initialize()
    {
        $this->getSource('robots');
        $this->hasMany('id', 'SomeNameSpace\RobotsParts', 'robots_id',array(
            'alias' => 'robotsparts',
        ));
    }`